# Same comments on all posts

Tags: theme-development, comments

I am working on a self-made theme and I have an issue where all of the comments are showing up on all the posts, instead of each post only showing their own comments.

I am using this code to display comments:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    // The title, content and some other html here
    wp_list_comments(array( 'callback' => 'comments_callback'), get_comments());
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And I have tried to both put this line inside and outside the loop, and still get the same result. I got com comments_callback funktion in a mu-plugins and the code for it looks like this:

```
<?php
function comments_callback( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    ?>
    <div class="the-comment">
      <div class="blog-comment-avatar">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-text">
      <p class="text-secondary comment-author"><?php comment_author(); ?></p>
        <?php comment_text(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add the full code of your template?

Comment: This can happen when you are overwriting the main query with a second, broken one.

Comment: I dont know what else you want? The whole mu-pugin is listed above, and the post is a standard loop containing the first-line. Nothing special or advanced.

Comment: @AhmedMahdi I have now updated my question with some more code showing how the loop looks like and where the comments are outputed

Comment: haven't tested your code but it looks like comment_author and comment_text need a $comment_ID that is not being passed correctly https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_text/ Have you tried querying comments directly? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue. It's being caused by the loop in your code:

> ```
> <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
>   <?php while (have_posts()): ?>
> ```

Replace that standard loop with `if ( have_comments() ) {...`, like this:

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) { ?>
    // The title, content and some other html here
    wp_list_comments(array( 'callback' => 'comments_callback'), get_comments());
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Glad to hear! That was a sneaky one.

Comment: Yes, it sure was! I've been really confused over this one since it was'nt a custom loop or anything, thanks alot for the help! :)